# Pandas - Grouping Rows With Same Value in Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here is the dataframe in question:

```
|City|District|Population| Code | ID |
| A  |   4    |   2000   |  3   | 21 |
| A  |   8    |   7000   |  3   | 21 |
| A  |   38   |   3000   |  3   | 21 |
| A  |   7    |   2000   |  3   | 21 |
| B  |   34   |   3000   |  6   | 84 |
| B  |   9    |   5000   |  6   | 84 |
| C  |   4    |   9000   |  1   | 28 |
| C  |   21   |   1000   |  1   | 28 |
| C  |   32   |   5000   |  1   | 28 |
| C  |   46   |   20     |  1   | 28 |
```

I want to regroup the population counts by city to have this kind of output:

```
|City|Population| Code | ID |
| A  |  14000   |  3   | 21 |
| B  |   8000   |  6   | 84 |
| C  |  15020   |  1   | 28 |
```

Comment: `groupby('City').Population.sum().reset_index()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang what if there are 10 other columns that I would like to conserve the way they are? (check edited question)

Comment: Simply add all grouped by fields in `groupby` as a list. Use also `as_index=False` to avoid the `reset_index` later.

Comment: the `as_index=False` makes a lot of sense. it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = df.groupby(['City', 'Code', 'ID'])['Population'].sum()
```

You can make a group by 'City', 'Code' and 'ID then make sum of 'population'.